# Problem displaying title revisions on profile activity tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, design, activity-summary

On some SE sites, entries for revised titles on a user's profile have insufficient line height, so the lines of the edited title end up overlapping.

For example, on [English](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/11387/lauren?tab=activity):

[image: Screenshot of the bug on English.SE]

Similarly on [Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/3312/aarthi?tab=activity):

[image: Screenshot of the bug on DIY.SE]

It only happens on profile pages (the diff on /posts/X/revisions looks fine), and only on some sites

Comment: eeek! i'm looking into this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a 200% font-size on that page we can't really explain (since the name `<h1>` in the upper left doesn't get that style anyway...there's something else with a higher specificity).

A fix for both the size and overlap will go out with the next build.