# Revision control -- Title Color Overlap

Tags: bug, status-completed, revisions-list

I am looking at the rev control for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7414183/revisions) and on my screen in Chrome 13.0.7 it looks like this:

[image]

This should be remedied because it can get hard to read if the title is more than one line.

It might just be a minor css issue.

The same happens if you click on the second option for side by side diffs:
[image]

This was an issue in July (on profile pages):
[Problem displaying title revisions on profile activity tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100059/155556), and it was marked as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) -- so it is probably the same issue, and just as easy to fix.

Comment: Probably the same problem as [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100059/problem-displaying-title-revisions-on-profile-activity-tab), but that fix was specific to the profile page

Comment: @MichaelMrozek ... I guess not...

Comment: @MichaelMrozek I added that as an addendum to my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The too low line-height for the headers was fixed for the Stack Exchange 2.0 sites, but was never pulled over to the Trilogy sites. Fixed in the next build.

Note that depending on a site's font settings, there may still be a slight overlap in the highlights, but it won't touch the actual letters (and thus hurt readability).

Comment: ...and [it's back](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230607/theres-something-funky-about-some-titles-in-revision-histories-here-on-meta). :/

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Already reported as [Side-by-side markdown title not so side-by-side](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230015)

Comment: @MartijnPieters yup, missed that somehow. Vote added. :)