# Side-by-side markdown title not so side-by-side

Tags: bug, design, meta

In edit revisions where a long enough title has been edited, the side-by-side  markdown view shows a large overlap when the title wraps:

[image]

This is a repeat of [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106171/revision-control-title-color-overlap) specific to the new Meta design. Looks like a line spacing adjustment is needed.

See this [sample revision list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/230009/revisions).

Comment: The dupe post was originally closed as a dupe of this post, but there's an answer there and none here, so I'm reversing it.