# Erroneously enthusiastic diff rendering marks entire revisions in Activity Summary in bright verdant splendour

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, activity-summary

At some point, [at least at the time of this report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100059/problem-displaying-title-revisions-on-profile-activity-tab), we had functional diff displays when you expanded a `revision` event on the `activity` tab of a user's profile.

Now, however, it looks like [the following mess of algae](https://history.stackexchange.com/users/43/wladimir-palant?tab=activity):

[image: Image of an entirely green revision, which was actually just a typo fix]

The only change in the above is that the word "take" there was originally "tak". An `e`. That's it. Good luck finding it.

It seems that the diff display has broken in some fashion so that it is under the impression that all of the post is new. I've seen this on all the Beta sites, here on Meta Stack Overflow, and a smattering of graduated sites, so I'm inclined to believe it's a global issue.

Could it be fixed to show the actual differences in the revisions?

Comment: Maybe that one "e" changed the whole context?

Comment: On the post revision history, the diff view still works.

Comment: +1 for freehand "Impressive Typo"

Comment: Off to look up "verdant"

Comment: ...no way! You *Anglais* have a word for everything. Need to keep this in mind.

Comment: @Pekka: Are you telling me that you Germans conquered Paris *twice* and didn't manage to steal any of their cool French words while you were there?

Comment: I can't tell if you're joking, @Pekka... usually we English speakers think of German as the language that has a word for everything. "_Schadenfreude_." "_Sturm und drang_." "_Der [blinkenlichten](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blinkenlights)_."

Comment: @mmyers, they probably did, but lost them [at the ends of the wars](http://forums.xkcd.com/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=21094#p631176).

Comment: @mmyers - what Pop says. The first thing that made it back across the border as reparations was truckfuls of stolen french words.

Comment: What is your tool of choice for writing "Impressive Type"? :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I am inclined to argue that this "e" totally changed the meaning of the post. So in its ultimate wisdom, the diff engine decided to treat this has a rewrite instead of an edit. I find that an extremely smart decision.

<sub>Also, possibly because of a Dapper issue, we failed to retrieve the previous revision to have something to compare to. But that's beside the point.

<sub><sub>Fixed in the next build.</sub></sub></sub>

Comment: Should we be concerned about the diff engine gaining sentience?